# STM32F3xx CAN (controller area network) Receive

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I am working with CAN of STM32F303K8. I can transmit data but I can't receive data; the function HAL_CAN_Receive() returns HAL_TIMEOUT. I am working with 1M and 32 clock.
can any one tell me how we use HAL_CAN_Receive() to  receive data frome CAN

Comment: Okay, two things. What is transmitting? And did you set up filters?

Comment: i didn't set up filters and i am transmitting data from an adapdater CAN -USB and also i tested with mbed.h it works but it didn't work with HAL_CAN_Receive()

Comment: may code main.c here [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302112/stm32f3xx-can-controller-area-network-receive-problem#302112]

Answer (score 4):

In order to receive CAN messages on STM32 you have to enable at least one filter.
The message is compared with all filters, and it needs to match at least one filter to be put in a fifo.

You can make a filter that matches all messages.

```
 sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
 sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
 sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
 sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
 sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
 sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
 sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
 sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
 sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
 sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 14;
```

Comment: and OP: I have the same problem, but using already the code you mentioned, and did not work for me... Do you meanwhile maybe have a different solution?